# Reasons to use an abstract class as the declared type instead of the subclass (Java)?

Tags: java, polymorphism, abstract-class

I am trying to understand this example of Java abstraction I came across. Under what conditions would I want to write:

`Animal myPig = new Pig();`

instead of:

`Pig myPig = new Pig();`

Here is the code:

```
// Abstract class
abstract class Animal {
  // Abstract method (does not have a body)
  public abstract void animalSound();
  // Regular method
  public void sleep() {
    System.out.println("Zzz");
  }
}

// Subclass (inherit from Animal)
class Pig extends Animal {
    @Override
  public void animalSound() {
    // The body of animalSound() is provided here
    System.out.println("The pig says: wee wee");
  }
}

class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Animal myPig = new Pig(); // Create a Pig object
    Pig myPig = new Pig(); // Line in question
    myPig.animalSound();
    myPig.sleep();
  }
}
```

Both lines give the same result, I just can't see any advantage of one use of the other or in what scenario one of them would make more sense.

Comment: If the variable has the potential to hold other kinds of `Animal`s, you would want it to be of the generic class rather than a child class

Comment: I feel this may be a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/383947) - I'd vote, but my vote is a hammer.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem Same. That's two of us.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Same. That's three of us.

Comment: OK, that's three votes, so I used my hammer.  I wish there was a way for golden badgers to deploy regular votes.

Comment: Also some good information from Erich Gamma [here](https://www.artima.com/articles/design-principles-from-design-patterns)